# Coverall branches [[0,0]] missed meaning?

Tags: code-coverage, coveralls

I'm just starting out with Coveralls and testing coverage and I see info such as this. What do the arrays mean? How should I interpret these? I can't seem to find anywhere in the docs or online regarding the meaning of these.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First index is **block number** and the second is **branch number** assigned by GCC

Basing my theory on [lcov documentation](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/geninfo.1.php) for branch coverage information

```
BRDA: line number,block number,branch number,taken

Block  number  and  branch  number are gcc internal IDs for the branch.
Taken is either '-' if the basic block containing the branch was  never
executed or a number indicating how often that branch was taken.
```